# Windows partition gone after installing Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, windows, system-installation

I installed Kali Linux with guided mode and with lvm on hard drive without creating a partition for kali Linux... But now i can not into Linux but can't on windows..plz help... Tried os-prober....and fdisk -l but it shows only Linux partition amd some efi file type.

Comment: Restore from backup. You've overwritten Windows.

Answer (score 1):

how to repair grub?
The first thing that you need to do,is to boot from a kali linux live ISO. After that, place to the Gparted, so that you can see the path where kali has been installed: usually it is in the File System that ends with ext4, depending on the file system you used during the installation. In my computer, the Kali linux system was in sda3, but it varies in different systems.
now you can run this code:

```
mount /dev/sda3 /mnt
mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev
mount --bind /dev/pts /mnt/dev/pts
mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc
mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys
chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/sda
update-grub
exit
umount /mnt/dev/pts
umount /mnt/dev
umount /mnt/proc
umount /mnt/sys
umount /mnt
```

This will restore the old kali linux boot loader, however, you will have to boot into kali linux live IOS must be unmout, as to add windows into the boot loader. the first time that booted, now you can run this code:

```
os-prober
update-grub
```

... and thats it.i wish it can help you.

Comment: If you've correctly interpreted the OP's question, thank you for this answer. It's not what I thought they'd asked, but I could easily have misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install Kali & MS Windows on same partition. As roaima's comment, you have to restore the backup (I hope you have it).

However, you have to shrink the existing Windows partition to make enough room to install Kali Linux on new partition. Use GParted from Kali live ISO or simply use Microsoft partition manager. Then use the new partition to install Kali and go head for next steps to setup grub and etc...